# Could we build a global renewable energy grid?

Tags: engineering, climate-change, carbon-based

I’m trying to build a post-fossil fuel world for my eco thriller. So in my head it works like this: Fossil fuel is outlawed internationally amd renewable energy is mandated; each country has a national grid, maybe contributes to a continental grid, but also signs up to a global grid. There would be proportional quotas according to resource and consumption. The power is generated by the country’s most abundant renewable resources e.g carbon capture and conversion, wind, solar etc.

I know the technology already exists to capture carbon from the air and either transport it as liquid co2 or convert it at source to hydrocarbon fuel. There are also methods of storing renewable energy locally to smooth out bumps in local supply (e.g pumped thermal storage) which would help with national grid management.

Would this work?

Comment: *"I know the technology already exists to capture carbon from the air"* they're called trees :))

Comment: Please edit the initial question and have it reopened after review. While reposting the question seems easy, it's a poor attempt of circumventing our quality standards.

Comment: Carbon capture and sequestration (CCS) is a net energy sink. You would lose more energy separating CO2 from air than you could ever expect to gain back. As such, an external energy source is required for any CCS activity. CCS is therefore NOT an "abundant renewable resource"

Comment: As long as the technical know how & political will exists of course .. the problem with the question is you appear to be asking us to engage in general spit balling in a wide range of technologies (& perhaps even discuss character actions, through the politicos) & this site doesn't do that .. or it's not supposed to.

Comment: This phrase doesn't make sense, ... *"The power is generated by the country’s most abundant renewable resources e.g carbon capture and conversion"*. Carbon capture is not a renewable energy source. It's a proposed method of **waste disposal**.

Comment: As to the broader issue of a global renewable energy grid, technically it would be possible; see [this](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2019/nov/20/billionaires-invest-in-giant-australian-solar-farm-to-supply-power-to-singapore). Politically things could get messy as happened when [Russia cut-off gas supplies to Ukraine](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-29521564). See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia%E2%80%93Ukraine_gas_disputes). In that situation it was gas, but it could have been electricity or hydrogen gas for a carbon free power station.

Comment: Also, read about the issues regarding [Nord Stream 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nord_Stream) which was developed by Russia to by-pass Ukraine because of the issues between the two countries. Transnational energy grids can get messy.

Comment: Thank you to those who posted answers - I found them really helpful. I understand I’ve violated some rules (including, I think, posting this comment!), so sorry about that. I’m literally new to the forum today and doing my best on a limited timeframe. I’ve tried to vote up the really helpful answers but have been unable to so just to say thank you.